# [hide], [show] and their spawnlings

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

There are numerous questions in both [hide](/questions/tagged/hide) and [show](/questions/tagged/show).  The majority of these questions are directly related to jQuery animations while a decent amount of others are in regards to hiding various *$x*.  The jQuery related questions would probably be better suited retagging hide/show to [animation](/questions/tagged/animation) or even [jquery-animation](/questions/tagged/jquery-animation) as the more general "hook" and specify that you are hiding/showing something with your animation.  The questions not related to animation effects should probably just have these tags removed altogether as they provide no helpful information.

In addition there's also [show-hide](/questions/tagged/show-hide), [showhide](/questions/tagged/showhide), [hideshow](/questions/tagged/hideshow), [auto-hide](/questions/tagged/auto-hide), [autohide](/questions/tagged/autohide).  Some of these like 'showhide/hideshow' and 'autohide/auto-hide' have just a few tags and I'll probably get rid of those today.  However, [show-hide](/questions/tagged/show-hide) has nearly 400 questions associated with it; it may be better to get rid of those tags en masse.

---

The only tags left from these are [hide](/questions/tagged/hide), [show](/questions/tagged/show) and [show-hide](/questions/tagged/show-hide) which represent about 1600~ questions.  With that many questions is there some mass action that can be taken to merge those tags with [animation](/questions/tagged/animation) or otherwise get rid of them?

Comment: All we need now are [rawhide], [hide-and-go-seek], and [hidebound]. And perhaps [showboat].

Comment: A moderator may help to retag [all posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/show+hide) (397) having both [tag:show] and [tag:hide] tags into [tag:show-hide].

Comment: Show and hide are *not* necessarily about animation!